# Love, fate and marriages

Tags: culture

Is there something like we get to marry the person that God has pre written for us in our fate? Because i have seen so many love stories which dating happens for years, they will be so in love but in the last minute even after the engagement the wedding is called off.They get married to someone else .So is it true that we get to marry the person written in our fate or anyone we like?

Comment: The more appropriate title would be: **Does free will exist?**. People of these days are highly deluded (thanks to Kali and Maya) and they mistake Lust with love and they choose material comforts over others. So, no use in discussing them. So, your question can be answered at questions [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2399/3500) and [Does Shiva or Vishnu or Trikaladarshi Yogi know our Aagami Karma or our free will?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10604/3500)

Comment: @The Destroyer--Do not frighten new joinees with jigsaw words.

Comment: @Durga--True...We get married wriiten as per our  fate. It is Lord Brahma who writes the fate for the whole lifetime. Accordingly it happens.

Comment: I agree with Destroyer and Partharsarthy both. If the love is result of lust then it is just lust we should not continue such love. We need to think about compatibility of nature and guna prakriti by comparing varnas. At the same time it is true that you may or may not find compatible person if your karma and fate is different. In later case we should forget about marriage and establishing samsara, and move towards higher goal of Life Moksha, moksha is attainable by Sharnagati to Lotus feet of Shriman Narayana in Kaliyuga. Path of Karma and Jnana is challenging and laborious.