# What happens to the devoted wife if her husband gets enlightenment?

Tags: brahman, lokas

According to Shāstras, if parents give their daughters to the guy whose ultimate aim is to attain Brahman, they attain Brahmāloka which is the second most difficult attainment after Moksha because it is easy to get Moksha in Brahmalok due to its environment. 
Also, husband & wife if devoted to each other are destined to marry in every birth due to concept of **Runanbandha** until they are devoted to each other.

Now, suppose husband attains Brahman or gets enlightenment, does enlightenment will automatically (if not suddenly, from Brahmāloka) follow to the wife because of inference from the concept of Runanbandha? It seems reasonable because a devoted wife or husband are destined to mingle again & again until devotion last. Wife being devoted to husband won't get any attainment other than Brahman if his husband attains Brahman only as she is supposed to mingle with him only.

So are there any scriptures which says so directly or indirectly?

---

This question has been dealt in [AnugitA](http://www.gita-society.com/section3/anugita.htm) (2nd discourse to Arjun by Lord Krishna) like this.

> On this, too, O chief of the descendants of Bharata! they relate this ancient story, (in the form of) a dialogue, which occurred, O son of Prithâ! between a husband and wife. A Brâhmana's wife, seeing the Brâhmana her husband, who had gone through all knowledge and experience, seated in seclusion, spoke to him (thus): **'What world, indeed, shall I go to, depending on you as (my) husband**, you who live renouncing (all) action, and who are harsh and undiscerning. **We have heard that wives attain to the worlds acquired by (their) husbands.** What goal, verily, shall I reach, having got you for my husband?' UpagitA - Chapter 5.

Comment: nothing really happens. Enlightenment is an individual quest, if one's spouse or parents are enlightened that wont make the relatives enlightened.

Comment: Obviously it is an individual quest. But I think the spouse will be destined to get enlightened within next single or few births because of Runanbandha.

Comment: It is helpful to the partner. because grihastha is combined upasana. both work as support system for each other.

Comment: Yes that's why there seems possibility. @RakeshJoshi.

Comment: It depends on the partner's outlook.  Buddha went out all alone, as the enlightenment is not easily transferred.

Comment: Sri Ramakrishna Paramahansa was enlightened soul and so was his wife, Sri Sarada Devi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A wife devoted to husband, depending on her *tapasyA* and *karma*, would **follow her husband** in form of consciousness or subtle body. There is an example in [AnushAsanika Parva](http://www.telugubhakti.com/telugupages/monthly/mahabharat/content1301.htm), where a half part of a devoted wife follows her husband to higher regions and remaining half also flows as a river (deity):

> the guest appeared in his splendid and glorious form. “O Sudarsana! I am Dharma Devata. (Deity of Dharma). I have come to test your mind and your devotion towards guests. *Mruthyu* is waiting to kill you whenever you transgress dharma. But you conquered Mruthyu. You have already conquered the six rivals viz., *Kama, krodha, lobha, moha, mada and matsarya*. **Your wife is your virtuous follower. You both are eligible to go to higher regions with this physical body whenever you wish.** With half of the power of your Tapas, your **wife Oghavati** transforms into a holy river and flows on this holy land. With the rest of the power of your Tapas, she remains with you in human form and serves you.

This same story is described with different words in [sacred-texts](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a002.htm):

> ... And thou shalt attain to all the worlds in this thy body, and as truly as the science of Yoga is within her control, **this highly blessed lady will follow thee with only half of her corporeal self, and with the other half will she be celebrated as the river Oghavati**!

<sub>**Trivia**: The river *OghAvati* is known as *Saraswati* today, which is very much near to Kurukshetra, where the MahAbhArata battle happened. The river was/is considered sacred since a long time.</sub>

Besides this, the famous examples are there of MAdari following PAndu to *Pitru* regions and GAndhAri following DhritarAshtra to higher regions after their deaths.

From these examples, we can assume that a wife is highly likely attain the "enlightenment" or the similar "*loka*" as her husband. Moreover, a form of *Bhakti* is also -- being in company of enlightened person. A devoted wife fulfils this criteria with flying colours!

> BG 13.26 - But others who are without [transcendental] knowledge, perform worship by hearing from others [who know], they also surely transcendent the death, being devoted to listening

<sub>Also refer [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8889/1049) for non-devoted wives.</sub>

Comment: You can make your answer more precise by reading anugitA. Please update sooner or later.

Comment: @Rohit. I havent read that. Feel free to edit or refer the relevant passage here.