# Is there any rule in Shastras for women to be kanyas even after marriage

Tags: dharma, marriage, dharma-shastras, manu-smriti

[Manu Smriti](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu03.htm) Says

> Sixteen (days and) nights (in each month), including four days which differ from the rest and are censured by the virtuous, (are called) the natural season of women. 
>   3.46
>
> But among these the first four, the eleventh and the thirteenth are (declared to be) forbidden; the remaining nights are recommended.
>   3.47
>
> He who avoids women on the six forbidden nights and on eight others, is (equal in chastity to) a student, in whichever order he may live. 
>   3.50

So it is possible for male grihastas to have innocence and chastity similar to that of Bramhacharis

Is it possible for women to have similar rules to posses chastity equal to that of a kanya(damsel) after marriage, to be specific marriage followed by loosing virginity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever conforms for men to [observe the vow of *Brahmacharya*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20701/1049), the same applies (vice a versa) for women as well.

> Bhishma said, ... As the sacred fire waits for libations to be poured upon it when the hour for Homa arrives, even so a woman, when her functional period is over, expects an act of congress with her husband. **One that never approaches one's spouses at any other time save after the functional period, is said to observe the vow of Brahmacharya**.
>   [[Anusasana Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b127.htm)

It says that, like how the divine drink is offered to the deity of fire when the time of *Homa* arrives during *Havana*, similarly when woman's menstrual cycle is over, she expects sexual congress with her husband (subduing the fire). If a person (husband or wife) have such congress only during the prescribed period, then he/she is on the path of *Brahmacharya*.

A woman observing the *Brahmacharya* can certainly be considered as chaste, as equivalent as a damsel (*kanya*).

Comment: +1 Good one! can you check in any of the dharma shastras for cross verification?

Comment: Thanks @Yogi. I don't have good hold over other books, hence it's least likely for me to be able to find the cross reference for above elsewhere, as this itself was rare gem of advise, which involved women as well. We can safely assume, that Bhishma gave all the essence of Dharma ShAstra to Yudhishtira, while being on bed of arrows. I think, woman who is surrendered to her husband, automatically gains all the advantages of those advises. It's similar to how [wife follows husband in higher regions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19510/1049).

Comment: Hmm, I agree with you Sri Bhishma was capable of being a Rajarishi, but we cannot deny possiblity of interpolation. So if this post doesn't get more relevant answers for more than 5 days. I will accept your answer.