# Can Sati leads to moksha if husband attains moksha?

Tags: mahabharata, moksha, marriage, sati

Consider the following paragraph related to the funeral rites of Vasudeva, the father of Krishna

> Thus addressed by Pritha’s son of pure deeds, all of them hastened
> their preparations with eagerness for achieving their safety. Arjuna
> passed that night in the mansion of Keshava. He was suddenly
> overwhelmed with great grief and stupefaction. **When morning dawned,
> Vasudeva of great energy and prowess attained, through the aid of
> Yoga, to the highest goal**. A loud and heart-rending sound of wailing
> was heard in Vasudeva’s mansion, uttered by the weeping ladies. They
> were seen with dishevelled hair and divested of ornaments and floral
> wreaths. Beating their breasts with their hands, they indulged in
> heart-rending lamentations. Those foremost of women, Devaki and Bhadra
> and Rohini and Madira threw themselves on the bodies of their lord.
> Then Partha caused the body of his uncle to be carried out on a costly
> vehicle borne on the shoulders of men. It was followed by all the
> citizens of Dwaraka and the people of the provinces, all of whom,
> deeply afflicted by grief, had been well-affected towards the deceased
> hero. Before that vehicle were borne the umbrella which had been held
> over his head at the conclusion of the horse-sacrifice he had achieved
> while living, and also the blazing fires he had daily worshipped, with
> the priests that had used to attend to them. The body of the hero was
> followed by his wives decked in ornaments and surrounded by thousands
> of women and thousands of their daughters-in-law. The last rites were
> then performed at that spot which had been agreeable to him while he
> was alive. **The four wives of that heroic son of Sura ascended the
> funeral pyre and were consumed with the body of their lord. All of
> them attained to those regions of felicity which were his.** The son of
> Pandu burnt the body of his uncle together with those four wives of
> his, using diverse kinds of scents and perfumed wood. As the funeral
> pyre blazed up, a loud sound was heard of the burning wood and other
> combustible materials, along with the clear chant of Samans and the
> wailing of the citizens and others who witnessed the rite. After it
> was all over, the boys of the Vrishni and Andhaka races, headed by
> Vajra, as also the ladies, offered oblations of water to the
> high-souled hero.
>
> [[Section 7, Mausala Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16007.htm)

The paragraph mentioned that Vasudeva attains moksha, the highest goal with the help of Yoga. And the four wives of Vasudeva underwent Sati in order to reach the loka in which Vasudeva is present.

If the Vasudeva attains moksha, there is an infinitesimal chance that he will take birth again in any loka. Then where did the four wives go? Do the "regions of felicity" mentioned refer to moksha? If yes, then is it safe to infer that Sati leads to moksha if the husband attains moksha?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19500/what-happens-to-the-devoted-wife-if-her-husband-gets-enlightenment