# Exact References of number of wives of krishna in mahabharat?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, reference-request, critical-edition, research

Please give exact shloka number(and its translation) in Mahabharat(not puranas) , where number of wives of krishna is mentioned, Esp. the 16000 wives in narakasura episode and other wives?

I will infinitely appreciate, if somebody additionally gives shloka number (and its translation) references from [**BORI edition of mahabharat**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-bori.html) ?

Comment: why do you want from bori edition ?

Comment: I have "not" said that I want "only from BORI". I have said that I want "also" from BORI. Having answer from both the  BORI edition and from popular(like KMGanguli) version - will make it a complete answer.

Comment: OK. FYI, whether BORI edition matches KMG's or not, BORI edition is known for its leftist/unorthodox personal mis-interpretations.. if you are interested in knowing more about the authors of the edition, you can see comments on this [meta-post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/945/is-name-calling-and-bigotry-allowed-on-this-site). And while this particular website may have an arbitrary rule that the contents of a book and its author must be judged separately, it is both useless and harmful in real-life. Even ganga-jal brought in a dog-skull is reprehensible.

Comment: btw, i think the exact number is 16,108. 16000 is just used as a short-form, (as in 1 lakh + 1 is still referred to as 1 lakh)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be found in **Mahabharata: Udyoga Parva: Bhagwat Yana Parva**.

Sanskrit shloka can be found [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs05155.htm):

> 8. संछिद्य मौरवान पाशान निहत्य मुरम ओजसा
>
>    निर्जित्य नरकं भौमम आहृत्य मणि कुण्डले
> 9. **षॊडश स्रीसहस्राणि** रत्नानि विविधानि च
>
>    परतिपेदे हृषीकेशः शार्ङ्गं च धनुर उत्तमम

The English translation for this is given [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05159.htm):

> Baffling the nooses of Mura and slaying by his might that Asura, and vanquishing Naraka, the son of the Earth, Hrishikesa, while recovering the begemmed ear-rings (of Aditi), with **sixteen thousand girls** and various kinds of jewels and gems, obtained that excellent bow called Sarnga.

The Sanskrit shloka can also be found in [Mahabharata-BORI](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-bori.html) > Devanagari (and other Indian scripts from each sarga page) > [५ उद्योगपर्वम्](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh05_sa.html):

> सञ्छिद्य मौरवान्पाशान्निहत्य मुरमोजसा |
>
> निर्जित्य नरकं भौममाहृत्य मणिकुण्डले ||८||
>
> **षोडश स्त्रीसहस्राणि** रत्नानि विविधानि च |
>
> प्रतिपेदे हृषीकेशः शार्ङ्गं च धनुरुत्तमम् ||९||

---

Related Post(s)

[Did Krishna have 16108 wives?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/290/did-krishna-have-16108-wives/)

Comment: thanks for answering from KM Ganguli version. If you can give from BORI version "also", then it will be very valuable.

Comment: @zaxebo1 updated the answer....

Comment: i think the exact number is 16,108

Comment: @ram OP was specifically asking for "Esp. the 16000 wives in narakasura episode" so provided answer on that point...however now added related q....

Comment: he also mentions 'other wives' just after the word episode, and his title also asks about exact number. when someone reads your quoted text, it seems like exact number is 16000 ?